# DllImport in Portable Class Library with .NET 4.5/Windows Store/WP8

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

If I have a portable class with .NET 4.5 and Windows Store, I can use DllImport. However, when I add WP8, it is no longer available, even though WP8 supports DllImport. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you can add `[DllImport ...]` in your C# WP8 project doesn't mean that it's supported.

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var v = GetCurrentThread();
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();
```

... will give a `NotSupportedException` in WP8. Even though [MSDN says that this is a supported Win32 API for WP8.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683182(v=vs.85).aspx)

That would also explain why you lose the ability to use `DllImport` in PCL...

Comment: Thanks Paul. You saved the remainder of my hair.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to use reflection to call DllImport in a PCL if DllImport is supported by the end exe?